# Edit binary data in PDF with SED / BBE (change colors in a PDF)

Tags: pdf, sed, colors, binary

I want to change some background colors in a batch of PDF's

I found out that the color information is stored in the **first** *stream - endstream* block
in a format like such: `1 1 1 sc` which in this example represents white `#FFFFFF`

here an example after I decode the binary stream with
`qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable IN.pdf OUT.pdf`

```
stream
q Q q /Cs1 cs 0.9686275 0.9725490 0.9764706 sc 0 12777 m 600 12777 l 600 0
l 0 0 l h f 0 12777 m 600 12777 l 600 0 l 0 0 l h f ➡️1 1 1 sc⬅️ 0 12575 m 600
12575 l 600 12308 l 0 12308 l h f 0.1254902 0.2666667 0.3921569 sc 0 872 m
600 872 l 600 462 l 0 462 l h f 0 462 m 600 462 l 600 0 l 0 0 l h f ➡️1 1 1
sc⬅️ 0 12297 m 600 12297 l 600 5122 l 0 5122 l h f 0.7411765 0.8980392 0.9725490
sc 23 7249 m 577 7249 l 577 6007 l 23 6007 l h f 1 0.9215686 0.9333333 sc
23 5848 m 577 5848 l 577 5533 l 23 5533 l h f 0.9686275 0.9725490 0.9764706
sc 23 5510 m 577 5510 l 577 5156 l 23 5156 l h f ➡️1 1 1 sc⬅️ 0 5110 m 600 5110
...
endstream
```

If I open the PDF in TextEdit and manually replace `1 1 1 sc` with `0 1 0 sc` my white background immediately changes to green after saving the PDF file.

How can I do this in an automated way with a Text Tool?

1. `sed 's/1 1 1 sc/0 1 0 sc/' IN.pdf > OUT.pdf`
   gives me the error: `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`
2. `bbe -e 's/0 1 1 sc/0 1 0 sc/' IN.pdf > OUT.pdf`
   no errors, OUT.pdf is written but no colors have changed
   `echo 'hello 1 1 1 sc world' | bbe -e 's/1 1 1 sc/0 1 0 sc/'`
   seems to work fine...

In the above stream (the first stream block) in the 1-page PDF file I need to replace only the second and third find. The second one has a line break?

Comment: is the `bbe` command shown above a typo?

Comment: This question should be asked on [su] instead, as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: The `IN.pdf` contains binary data, is that correct? And the string `1 1 1 sc` is not in `IN.pdf`, but it appears in the output of `qpdf`, is that right?

Comment: --jhnc, No, which typo? I get no errors. --Ken, guess you are correct... --Beta, yes in the decoded OUT.pdf. I thought bbe could handle the decoding for a search and replace?

Comment: Your command 1 searches for `1 1 1 sc`; your command 2 searches for `0 1 1 sc`.

Comment: I guess you should first decode your IN.pdf with qpdf and then use `sed` on that decoded file, then back convert it to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely clear what you are doing.

You mention commands:

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable IN.pdf OUT.pdf

sed 's/1 1 1 sc/0 1 0 sc/' IN.pdf > OUT.pdf

bbe -e 's/0 1 1 sc/0 1 0 sc/' IN.pdf > OUT.pdf
```

It is not obvious if `IN.pdf` in the `sed` or `bbe` commands is the same `IN.pdf` file as the `qpdf` command.

If all three commands are using the same file as input, then that can explain why `bbe` fails.

Another possibility is that the `bbe` command shown is the command you are actually using and not a typo. It does not actually look for the string `1 1 1 sc`.

---

`sed` is not designed to work with binary data.
Although the GNU implementation has a non-standard `-z` option to help read binary files, it still works on a form of "lines". Perl can be used as an improved sed here.

To change only the first three instances of the string `1 1 1 sc` in the file, you could try:

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable IN.pdf - |\
perl -0777 -pe 'for $i (1..3) { s/1 1 1 sc/0 1 0 sc/ }' |\
qpdf - OUT.pdf
```

In this Perl command:

- `-0777` - treat entire input as single record
- `-pe` - run command on each record, then print (like sed)
- `for $i (1..3) { ... }` - run three times
- `s/.../.../` - similar to `sed`'s s/// command

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes all the same IN.pdf file. I thought bbe could decode the stream and replace the characters, I guess I was wrong. btw the 0 1 1 for bbe was indeed a typo

Answer (score 0):

I think I will tackle this task with PikePDF, a Python library which seems to be able to work with content streams: https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/content_streams.html

I was just able to [Pretty Print](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/content_streams.html#pretty-printing-content-streams) the content streams by using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pikepdf import Pdf
import pikepdf

with pikepdf.open('IN.pdf') as pdf:
    page         = pdf.pages[0]
    instructions = pikepdf.parse_content_stream(page)
    data         = pikepdf.unparse_content_stream(instructions)
    print(data.decode('ascii'))
```

Now working my way to actual [Edit](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/content_streams.html#editing-a-content-stream) the content stream ..........

Here the stream fragment from my question, pretty printed:

```
q
Q
q
/Cs1 cs
0.9686275 0.9725490 0.9764706 sc
0 12777 m
600 12777 l
600 0 l
0 0 l
h
f
0 12777 m
600 12777 l
600 0 l
0 0 l
h
f
➡️1 1 1 sc⬅️
0 12575 m
600 12575 l
600 12308 l
0 12308 l
h
f
0.1254902 0.2666667 0.3921569 sc
0 872 m
600 872 l
600 462 l
0 462 l
h
f
0 462 m
600 462 l
600 0 l
0 0 l
h
f
➡️1 1 1 sc⬅️
0 12297 m
600 12297 l
600 5122 l
0 5122 l
h
f
0.7411765 0.8980392 0.9725490 sc
23 7249 m
577 7249 l
577 6007 l
23 6007 l
h
f
1 0.9215686 0.9333333 sc
23 5848 m
577 5848 l
577 5533 l
23 5533 l
h
f
0.9686275 0.9725490 0.9764706 sc
23 5510 m
577 5510 l
577 5156 l
23 5156 l
h
f
➡️1 1 1 sc⬅️
0 5110 m
600 5110
```

Some more info about the color value:
Just divide the RGB values by 255
for example:

DeepSkyBlue = #00bfff = RGB(0, 191, 255)
0/255 = 0
191/255 = 0.7490196
255/255 = 1

```
0 0.7490196 1 sc
```